# Importing .XLSX file to Navision throws an error verticalDpi has invalid value '0'

Tags: excel, openxml, navision

I have an excel file that I'm importing to Microsoft Navision and now when Upload it throws an error "The spreadsheet is corrupted.
The following error occurred: The attribute 'verticalDpi' has invalid
value '0' The Minlnclusive constraint failed. The value must be
greater than or equal to 1.." , with other files it works fine but not this. Tinkering in C# with openxml library I found that other files that work don't even have pageSetup class I.e. ['code example'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx8o8.png) returns null. So I guess my question is *how to Delete class PageSetup from workbook*. If my assumption is wrong maybe there are other ways to solve problem?

Tried changing margins in excel 'Page Setup', tried opening file in C# with openxml library and changing page setup verticaldpi, page margins ( top, bottom)

Edit
After writing a question I found a solution, for my use case the problem was that particular .xlsx file created PageSetup class, using C# with OpenXLM library I read workbook and then sheet by sheet deleted PageSetup https://prnt.sc/hfLz8TBqzgke .

Comment: After writing a question I found a solution, for my use case the problem was that particular .xlsx file created PageSetup class, using C# with OpenXLM library I read workbook and then sheet by sheet deleted PageSetup https://prnt.sc/hfLz8TBqzgke .